# Trickering VBA-Excel ListObjects as a full interface with MsSQL for Win/Mac compatibility

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, windows, macos

*Management order, and IT are there to make things done …, I say that to explain why we need excels with MsSQL connections working on MAC and Windows without need of any driver installation, just open and go… so no ADODB, no sql driver, no… (we know, security may not be the best in this approach, but side-measurements are taken, so info in not available for more than few seconds, connections monitored, data integrity, and IP filtering active). Said all that:*

Using ListObjects we have managed to make SELCTS and INSERTS on any table using the basic-out-of-the-box excel on both mac and Windows, here the code of an excel module externally callable:

```
    Dim internalSheet As Worksheet  
    Dim destinationCells As Range   
    
    Dim connstring As String
    Dim sqlstring As String


Sub test_MSSQL()
    
    Call setEnviroment
    Call clearObjects
    
    Set destinationCells = internalSheet.Range("A5")
    
    
    sqlstring = '....'
    Call updateMETA
    Set destinationCells = destinationCells.Offset(2, 0)

    End Sub


Private Sub setEnviroment()
    Set internalSheet = Sheets("sheet_for_MsSQL") 
    sLogon = "UID=myUser;Pwd=myPwd;"
    connstring = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=myServer.database.windows.net;Database=myDb;" & sLogon
    End Sub



Private Sub clearObjects()
    For Each lo In internalSheet.ListObjects
        lo.Delete
        Next lo
    End Sub


Private Sub execute_MSsqlstring() 
   

    Debug.Print "execute_MSsqlstring:len::"; Len(sqlstring)
    Debug.Print sqlstring
        
    On Error GoTo justAnError
    
    With internalSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=connstring, Destination:=destinationCells).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array(sqlstring)
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells      
        .SavePassword = True
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    

justAnError:

    destinationCells.Offset(3, 0) = Str(Err.Number)
    

    End Sub
```

As you can see, we construct the sql sentence we wish and hit the server with it, works perfectly with SELCTS (obviously) and with INSERTS, except for the 255 characters’ limit imposed by the vba objects meta characters limitations that force “sqlstring” to be maximum 255 characters.
Query examples:

```
    timeset = Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    
    sqlstring = "INSERT INTO myTable(_ident, _meta_key, _meta_value, requested_by, requested_at) " & _
                " VALUES ( " + var_ident + ",'" + var_meta_key + "','" + var_meta_value + "','test_from_excel', '" + timeset + "') "
   
    sqlstring = "SELECT TOP (1) _meta_value FROM myTable" & _
                " where _ident = '" + var_ident + "' and _meta_key = '" +var_meta_key + "'" & _
                " order by _id desc"
```

But not for the UPDATE queries, trying executing that, it returns the same error raise by the  INSERT (1004) cached by the exception handling correctly, but server do not suffer any change
Query example:

```
sqlstring = "UPDATE myTable SET _meta_value = 'new value' " & _
            " WHERE  _ident=" + var_ident + ";"
```

First objective, and to overcome the 255 character limitations, is to, once made a first INSERT with “part” of the meta_value field, make a second UPDATE to complete the meta_value field. But sure more will follow.

```
sqlstring = "UPDATE myTable SET _meta_value = CONCAT(_meta_value, '" + var_meta_value + "' )" & _
            " WHERE  _ident = " + var_ident + " "
```

**Any help on this matter ?**

*Note: extensive search only found one result using UPDATEs and ListObjects:*
[Update case when sql query to vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278787/update-case-when-sql-query-to-vba)
*and got recomendation of using another connection strategy. We know is not the most standard aproach, but so far, only solution found working install-free on both mac and windows, so we will prefer not to "try odbcd" or similars*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA string 255 character limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040826/vba-string-255-character-limitation) there is no such thing, it is purely a debugger display limitation

Comment: Note by the way that you are dangerously open to SQL injection and syntax errors obviously

Comment: Pretty much no idea what you were talking about there.  The only advise I could give is to use `&` instead of `+`.... 1+1 is 2, 1 & 1 is 11.  As for the question - not really sure what it was.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook thanks a lot, yes, indeed I use sometime & but not always, I will clean up

Comment: @Charlieface, that I though for a moment, but it has been an extensive text, as soon as the sql string goes beyong 255 chars, things stop to work, I am looking for a test you can replicate

Comment: @Charlieface, we are really aware about the security implications, but so far, no other methot work on mac and windows without installation